# Who can use a Spell Scroll scribed by a bard who learned the spell using the Magical Secrets feature, if it is not normally on the bard spell list?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, class-feature, bard

When a bard learns a spell using the Magical Secrets feature, it counts as a bard spell. Of note, should they replace any spell learned via Magical Secrets at a later level, they can only replace it with one from the bard spell list. Rules designer Jeremy Crawford actually did [make a ruling on Twitter regarding this](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/12/13/a-spell-learned-via-magical-secrets/), so this is clear: replacing one's Magical Secrets spell is easily done - it is just somewhat unwise to do so.

Say a bard picks [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) as a spell. Massive boon! [For dirt cheap, they can print them off as *spell scrolls*.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-can-a-character-create-a-spell-scroll) Now, [who can use that *spell scroll*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51979/who-can-use-magic-scrolls)?

I see three possibilities:

1. This is a wizard spell on the wizard list - designed for wizards. Clearly **only a wizard** can use a wizard spell on the wizard list designed specifically for wizarding ways, right? So obvious: a wizard buying this spell can transcribe it into their book (with a good roll on a good day) - or simply use it and get themselves a familiar.
2. Any Magical Secrets spell, no matter which spell list it once came from, counts as a **bard** spell for all intents and purposes (i.e. "learning, casting and recording"). Should a bard make such a *spell scroll*, any other bard can use it. A "secret" no longer! But to be clear, if it *is* a bard spell, only bards could use this magic item. A wizard would not ever figure it out. A druid would have no chance. A barbarian would accidentally use this scroll as a fire-starter.
3. You can use any scroll if the spell is **on your class list**. So almost anyone can use that [*charm person*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person) scroll. Thus, the bard scribing such a *spell scroll* cannot even use it themselves. Imagine the ignominy with scribing any spell from Magical Secrets: "I cannot read any of what I just wrote down."

Which interpretation is correct?

(I did search to check whether this was a repeat of a previous question before posting.)

Comment: I personally would recommend leaving out potential answers from your question. If you believe those are all reasonable and possible, you can always self-answer, but otherwise I'd not lead the community to an answer but let us figure it out.

Comment: @NautArch i am mildly addicted (*considering therapy*) to adding flip and quirky comments to my questions. It is deeply enjoyable & even a bit cathartic to make fun of my own ideas. So sorry / hard to quit.

Comment: I like the flip and quirky comments/scenarios! I just don't like the pseudo answers :(

Comment: @NautArch I find "Here are several possible answers I'm considering, and the reasons for them" to be a useful addition to a question, as it often spotlights where the confusion lies.

Comment: @MarkWells I can kind of see that, but usually we like answers in answers. Adding them to questions obscures the question and prompts answer direction when that may not be helpful. However, it's not a huge deal.

Comment: To solve all your concerns: i do both - and both work. I get FAR more upvotes when i put half-answers into my questions though. The person who answers gets about double my upvote score, regardless of quality (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Spell scrolls don't care who created them.

The rules for using [spell scrolls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) say:

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell without providing any material components.

The scroll doesn't care about the class of its creator. The only requirement is that the particular spell appears on your class's spell list.

#### Magical Secrets spells count as Bard spells.

As for your situation where the Bard has a scroll bearing one of their Magical Secrets spells, the [Magical Secrets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#MagicalSecrets-592) feature description has this to say:

> The chosen spells count as bard spells for you.

So a Bard would be able to use a spell scroll bearing one of their spells learned through Magical Secrets. That is, if Jimmy Page (a bard) learns *haste* through Magical Secrets, he can use a *haste* spell scroll created by *anyone*, no matter their class. But if Jimmy Page learns *haste* through Magical Secrets and creates a *haste* spell scroll, Robert Plant (another bard) can only use the *haste* spell scroll if he also learns *haste* with Magical Secrets.

Comment: It's worth explicitly pointing out in the last section that Magical Secrets only count as bard spells for bards that pick them as Magical Secrets - so even if one bard's able to make a scroll of a spell not on the bard spell list that they've learned using Magical Secrets, a different bard won't be able to use that scroll unless it's on their spell list as well (e.g. if they gain it via Magical Secrets themselves).

Comment: @V2Blast Thank you. Ironically this is exactly the answer i was seeking. 'The best lines are always in the comments' as they say in Reddit.

Comment: @V2Blast I'm trying to figure out how my last sentence doesn't already say that.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: Your answer certainly implies it (in that scrolls don't care who makes them), but it never explicitly states that a bard can use a scroll of a spell they could learn via Magical Secrets (without multiclassing or whatever) *only if that particular bard has chosen that spell with the Magical Secrets feature themselves*. It's worth stating that explicitly. You say "Magical Secrets spells count as Bard spells", but the key restriction is that they count as bard spells for only that bard - not all bards.

Comment: @V2Blast Maybe I'm having a brain fart. My last sentence says, "So a Bard would be able to use a spell scroll bearing one of their spells learned through Magical Secrets." Isn't this what you're saying?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: As I said... That sentence *implies* "other bards can't unless they learn the spell with Magical Secrets", but doesn't explicitly *state* it. The question's not only about whether bards can use a scroll they make themselves for a spell not normally on the bard list that they learn via Magical Secrets, but about who in general can use such a scroll.

Comment: Surely Led Zeppelin can help explain this.